# dynamic query sorting with Peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I'm having trouble assembling dynamic sorting with my Peewee python app.

*Catalog is a Model object from playhouse.signals*
*Database is MariaDB*

I can sort by 2 fields like this:

`resultset = Catalog.select().where(...).order_by(Catalog.app_team,Catalog.domain)`

I can use a dynamic sort field like this:

```
sortlist = []
opt = 'domain'
sortlist.append(getattr(Catalog,opt))
resultset = Catalog.select().where(...).order_by(sortlist)
```

But I can't see how to do more than one dynamic field.  It fails if I pass it a list of 2 objects.

I tried passing a string like 'Catalog.app_team,Catalog.domain' but a string is ignored.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you have to use `*` to unpack list - `order_by(*sortlist)`

Comment: It worked.  Thank you so much!  Still new to python and this opens my eyes about what packing/unpacking is for.